# Embed tag using $scope variable containing url

Tags: angularjs, html

I want to insert external URL into views embed tag using Angular 1.3 controller's scope variable. 
In controller I tried:

```
  $scope.printUrl = "http://example.net";

  $scope.printUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://example.net");

  $scope.printUrl = $sce.trustAsUrl("http://example.net");
```

And in view:

```
    <embed width="800px;" height="450px;" ng-bind-html="{{printUrl}}">

<embed width="800px;" height="450px;" src="{{printUrl}}">

<embed width="800px;" height="450px;" ng-src="{{printUrl}}">
```

Case with src works as i can see message:

```
Cannot GET /%7B%7BprintUrl%7D%7D
```

I read also on w3schools, that

> The  tag is new in HTML5, and will validate in an HTML5 page.

UPDATE

http://plnkr.co/edit/yDAYclWzTQNMKlzqwEGX?p=preview

Comment: ng-src should work. Can you provide a plunkr ?

Comment: As in plunker ng-src doesn't provide solution, because website referenced in src should be visible in embeeded dom part.

Comment: Is there any alternative opposite to embed tag, so I can embed external webpage in my angular page?